# User.Claims is empty in Blazor Wasm hosted

Tags: jwt, authorization, blazor-webassembly, openiddict

I am working on a hosted Blazor webassembly app.

After the user logins into the application, I get the JWT token from OpenIdDict server, parse it and create

```
new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(list of claims parsed from jwt token))
```

But when I try to authorize a view, in the

```
AuthorizationHandler.HandleRequirementAsync(...)
```

method, `context.User.Claims` is empty, but `context.User.Identity.Claims` is populated with my claims.

Why is `context.User.Claims` empty but `context.User.Identity.Claims` is not and how can I get `context.User.Claims` to be populated also?

Thanks